# Polystyrene scent in bedroom

Tags: safety, bedroom, smell, polyurethane

I want to store boardgames on the top of the wardrobe in my bedroom. Unfortunately, there are a few screw and wooden lists on the top of it, which makes it impossible to store anything on the otherwise flat-top wardrobe.

To fix it, I bought a polystyrene plate, which I want to put on the top of the wardrobe (so the screws and lists just digs into the polystyrene instead).

My issue is: The polystyrene plate which I bought from the local DIY retailer smells pretty chemically, so I am unsure whether it would be wise to place it in a bedroom, which usually has its doors and windows closed at night (so the ventilation isn't the best while I sleep). I figured to begin with that I could use polystyrene safely, since it is used for food-packaging, etc.

My question is thus: Is the scent from polystyrene hazardous and is it temporary (since food-packaging does not smell)? Also in case it is dangerous, are there some variation of polystyrene plates, which I can use in my bedroom? (Perhaps the ones I bought was bad for this, since they were low-priced products bought at some DIY centre).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New plastic off-gasses. Leave it in your car for a week, most of it will go away.

None of it is good, and yes, food containers do leach into food.

Polystyrene less than most, but you're not getting heavily processed polystyrene foam, which stopped off-gassing while it was still "sand" in the railcar, before it reached the foaming plant.  You are getting solid polystyrene like is used in model airplanes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm much more at rest now. I'll just leave them at my loft for a week or so then and wait with my small DIY project.  

The reason I did not use plywood was that: 1) polystyrene was cheaper. 2) I can "force" the screws into the polystyrene (the screws has about 0.5cm exposed) unlike the plywood, where I had to drill them. Just seemed as the more easy choice.

Comment: I'm amused at the "leave in the car" suggestion. One could almost consider it would result in a new "new car smell." More seriously, the off-gassing may condense on the windows and create some fogging, depending on the amount released. High temperatures in the vehicle while sitting in the sun may be detrimental to the plastic as well. oPolo's response to let them off-gas where they sit shows his acceptance of the answer and a suitable adjustment.